# Is there a BigQuery version of isnumeric

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to test if a field is numeric or not using standard SQL in BigQuery.

The example below works and is similar to what I have done in Cognos using TRANSLATE('mystring','1234567890.','') but its not very elegant.

```
SELECT
IF(LENGTH(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE('1234.56','1',''),'2',''),'3',''),'4',''),'5',''),'6',''),'7',''),'8',''),'9',''),'0',''),'.',''))=0,
'A number',
'Not a number')
```

Answer (score 21):

You can use `SAFE_CAST` to try casting to a number. `SAFE_CAST` casts similar to `CAST`, but if casting fails, instead of erring `null` is returned.

For example you can do:

```
SAFE_CAST('1234567890' AS FLOAT64);
```

which will return `1.23456789E9`

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for both suggestions, both work a treat and I have gone for the SAFE_CAST option as it runs a fraction quicker.

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '1234.56' col UNION ALL
  SELECT '1234.' col UNION ALL
  SELECT '1234' col UNION ALL
  SELECT '.56' col UNION ALL
  SELECT '1234..56' col UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a1234.56' 
 )
 SELECT
   col,
   if(SAFE_CAST(col AS FLOAT64) is null,'Not a number', 'A number')
 FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

Answer (score 2):

> but its not very elegant

Below examples for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '1234.56' col UNION ALL
  SELECT '1234.' col UNION ALL
  SELECT '1234' col UNION ALL
  SELECT '.56' col UNION ALL
  SELECT '1234..56' col UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a1234.56' 
)
SELECT
  col,
  IF(LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(col, r'[\d.]', '')) = 0, 'A number', 'Not a number') ,
  IF(REGEXP_CONTAINS(col, r'^\d*.?\d*$'), 'A number', 'Not a number') 
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

Answer (score -2):

I think that we could use translate function to replace digits from 0 to 9
by 0 (let's say string_1 ) and then compare it to a string (let's say String_2) that equals to as much of 0 as then lengh of String_1.

```
(translate(src.NUM_BU , '0123456789', '0000000000')) 
= 
rpad('', length((translate(src.NUM_BU , '0123456789', '0000000000'))), '0')
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.