# IS_NUMERIC and IS_SPACES equivalent in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, migration, informatica-powercenter, bigquery-udf

As part of migration from Informatica to Big Query, anyone knows Informatica functions IS_NUMERIC and IS_SPACES equivalent in Big query?

For now haven't found any alternative for this. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Did you try BigQuery [regex_contains](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#regexp_contains) function?

Comment: Please have a look at this answer for SAFE_CAST that can be used for checking if an expression is numeric: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52081390/14072498

Answer (score 1):

If you want to validate whether a value is numeric you can make use if the `regex_contains` function as documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#regexp_contains).

According to the Google documentation this function

> Returns TRUE if value is a partial match for the regular expression,
> regexp.
>
> If the regexp argument is invalid, the function returns an error.

You can try this regex for numeric datatype: `REGEXP_CONTAINS(my_column, r'^\d+$')`